# Javascript array from string of numbers

Tags: javascript

I am trying to work with arrays in javascript.  Consider the following code:

```
 var visList = '1234,5678,9'
 var visListArray = new Array(visList);
 for (i = 0; i <= visListArray.length - 1; i++)
 {
      alert(visListArray[i]);
 }
```

Why doesn't this split the array into individual numbers instead of all of them clumped together?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create the array by calling `split()` on the string:

```
var visList = '1234,5678,9'  
var visListArray = visList.split(",");
```

You cannot substitue a string that looks like code for actual code.  While this would work:

```
var visListArray = new Array(1234,5678,9);
```

Yours doesn't because the string is not interpreted by the Array constructor as 3 comma separated arguments, it is interpreted as one string.

**Edit:** Note that calling `split()` on a string results in an Array of strings.  If you want an Array of numbers, you'll need to iterate the Array converting each string to a number.  One convenient way to do that is to use the [`map()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
visListArray = visList.split(",").map(function (item) {
    return +item;
});
```

See the [compatibility note](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Compatibility) for using `map()` in older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

because its an string, try this:

```
var visList = '1234,5678,9'
var visListArray = [].concat(visList.split(','));
for (i = 0; i <= visListArray.length - 1; i++) {
    alert(visListArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: to initialize the array with starting values,

Comment: @Shlomi - the call to concat is totally redundant.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [string.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```
var visList = '1234,5678,9'
var visListArray = visList.split(",");

for (i = 0; i <= visListArray.length - 1; i++)
{
    alert(visListArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: The OP doesn't **have** to use split, something like `var s = '1234,5678,9'.match(/\d+/g);` will do the trick also.

Answer (score 1):

To convert a symbol-separated list into an array, you may use *split(symbol):*

```
var list = "1221,2323,4554,7667".split(",");
for (var i = 0, il = list.length; i < il; i++) {
    alert( +list[i] ); // a casting from string to number
}
```